# TYPO3: clear indexed search cache

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript

When I use the search function on my website, it shows results with old content. I tried to clear all caches but it doesn't solve the issue.

I am not sure if I should truncate some tables in the DB and how safe this is.

By the way I don't have any "indexed search" option in the Backend under "Info".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which TYPO3 Version are you using? With TYPO3 8.7 (not sure if also with 7.6) the module moved to an own one called "Indexing".

Anyway you shouldn't get any problem truncating the indexed_search tables in the DB as they get shipped without data when you install indexed_search.

To be sure, just make a backup of the tables.

Comment: To be more precise, one may truncate all the `index_*` tables except `index_config` (may contain user-defined crawler configuration), `index_stat_search` (statistics, nothing to do with indexing) and `index_stat_word` (statistics as well)

Comment: I agree with the `index_config` but the statistic tables im not sure what they contain, as I'm not longer working with indexed_search. If the statistics are just about what a user search, then they should of course not be cleared. :)

Comment: I am using version 7.6. You were right, there is an "Indexing" module in the BE. I did truncate all the index tables expect index_config but now the search function doesn't find any result.

Comment: Have you opened the website without beeing logged in to the backend? Other browser for example?

Comment: I tried after logging out and with other browsers. All my index tables are empty except index_stat_search and index_stat_word. It seems like the pages are not being indexed anymore. By the way I am in DEV environment, I don't know if crawling is disabled in that case ?

Comment: @user6800816 Go to "Extension Manager", find `indexed_search` there and check if checkbox *Disable Indexing in Frontend* is enabled. If co, then your website uses a `crawler` extnesion and you need to run it either from command line or via TYPO3 Scheduler.

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi Yes the checkbox is unchecked. I also noticed the extension "indexed_search_mysql" is disabled. I looked into the task scheduler but I can't anything relative to indexing. Unfortunately I can't find any crawler extension installed ...

Comment: @user6800816 in your case seems like crawler is not needed (checkbox unchecked). Check then if `config.index_enable` is set in your TS.